# finding a regions in python list

Tags: python

I have signal stored as list of nonnegative numbers. I looks similar to:

00000000012340000000111111111110000000

What is the quickest way to find all positions of zeros segments. I need **begin**, **end** and **middle point** of each segment. Signal my start with any value.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, and your results

Comment: What do you mean by "quickest"? run-time-wise fastest, or quick to write (e.g. a one-liner)?

Comment: There is no possibility to paste entire code of my project. I need a general idea, that's way I prepared simplified example.

Comment: Yes, run-time-wise fastest. Data stored as np.uint16 are bigger than 20MB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this is an answer:

```
signal = [0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]
segments = []
segmentsCoords = []

inSegment = False
for i in xrange(len(signal)):
    if inSegment and signal[i] == 0:
        continue
    elif not inSegment and signal[i] == 0:
        inSegment = True
        begin = i 
    elif inSegment and signal[i] != 0:
        inSegment = False
        end = i 
        segments.append((end-begin)/2+begin)
        segmentsCoords.append([begin, end])
    elif not inSegment and signal[i]:
        continue
if signal[-1] == 0:
    end = len(signal)
    segments.append((end-begin)/2+begin)
    segmentsCoords.append([begin, end])

print segmentsCoords
print segments
```